# Realm to many query not live

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, realm

I have two models Parent and Child (one to many), Parent contains IList Children.

In my viewmodel I have a ListView bound to a property ChildList.

```
ChildList = _dataService.Realm.All<Parent>().First(d => d.ParentId == "MyParentIdentifier").Children;
```

Will result in a live query (if I add or delete a Child to the IList it will be reflected in the UI).

```
ChildList = _dataService.Realm.All<Parent>().First(d => d.ParentId == "MyParentIdentifier").Children.Where(d => d.ChildName.StartsWith("A"));
```

Will not result in a live query. The UI will only update after closing and re-opening the page.

How can I create a live query from this setup? I've also tried adding a backlink property to the Child model and a query like:

```
ChildList = _dataService.Realm.All<Child>().Where(d => d.Parent.ParentId == "MyParentIdentifier");
```

But this will result in a crash with error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The left-hand side of the Equal operator
>   must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm. Unable to
>   process 'd.Parent.ParentId'.

Comment: Queries across backlinks should be supported according to https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

Realm .NET doesn't currently support traversing properties (`d.Parent.ParentId`), but it supports object comparison:

```
var parent = _dataService.Realm.Find<Parent>("MyParentIdentifier");
ChildList = _dataService.Realm.All<Child>().Where(c => c.Parent == parent);
```

Comment: var parent = _dataService.Realm.All<User>().First(d => d.MyParentString = "What I want");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parent.MyParentString);

ChildList = _dataService.Realm.All<Child>().Where(d => d.Parent == parent);

Not quite the same, but I'd think equivalent - the print statement will return the right value but the child list query will give me the same error as my original post. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What version of the library are you using? This should definitely work with the latest one.

Comment: I've had to downgrade to 1.5, but when testing on the latest stable I still have the same error. My backlinks code in the model is just

`[Backlink(nameof(Parent.Children))]
public IQueryable<Parent> Parents { get; }

public Parent Parent => Parents.SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: `Parent` is not managed by Realm which is why you get this error. You should switch `Parent.Children` to be the backlink property, but that would mean you can only have 1 parent per child.